# has HITBTC exchange stolen my entire money $1600+ today

Tags: blockchain, hitbtc

This morning I tried to move the entire $1600 from hitbtc to my personal blockchain account,   I took time-stamped screenshots throughout the process.
In the evening the transaction appeared in my  HITBTC account but no green tick like the previous transactions. Naturally one starts  to assume the thing is just pending.  But the transaction hash  560b58a33f380b87940917790f046026d269202c8636c9bf842e6af80064a828
is showing transaction not found/  PLEASE TELL ME IF IT IS POSSIBLE HITBTC STOLE THE MONEY. I HAVE BEEN USING A SUFF LONG PASSWORD AND GOOGLE AUTHENTICATOR,  ALSO THERE IS AN ERROR SHOWING IN MY HITBTC ACCOUNT THIS EVENING WHEN I TRY TO DEPOSIT-JUST GIVES NO DEPOSIT ADDRESS-just ERROR.

I also saw a posting on this forum which is the reason I joined

---------------------------------------------------------------------------- with a link 'view transaction'. If I click on this link it takes me to https://insight.bitpay.com/ and shows "TRANSACTION NOT FOUND". I also searched in blockchain.info and some other explorers all show transaction not found. So far not much luck from Gemini support. I am getting desperate with Gemini.

Here is the transaction ID; e1e405bdd06b3ab23c3099f41f5da58ea0f5cf0bd2f891850c1d5c70fedfdb20

What is happening with this transaction? What does "transaction not found" mean?
Is this waiting in miner's mempool to be picked up?
No. Broadcasted transactions are visible on block-explorer sites (in most cases)

Is this unconfirmed and already dropped from the blockchain network.
It is unconfirmed, but not because already dropped, but because not yet broadcasted

Transaction have some error to start with and never broadcasted on blockchain network?
May be. Only sender knows the correct answer

None of the above and have some other issue?

### If it is not seen - it does not exist. Point

So  i do not know blockchain technology.  Can you please explain to me if there is any way to debug the error or get my money back. If you recover my $1600 I promise you $200 straight away

Comment: I found your [first transaction](https://btc.com/560b58a33f380b87940917790f046026d269202c8636c9bf842e6af80064a828), what is the problem with e1e405bdd06b3ab23c3099f41f5da58ea0f5cf0bd2f891850c1d5c70fedfdb20 ?

Comment: If a transfer from an exchange has gone missing, really your only option is to contact their support, there's nothing else anyone can do. If the transaction is "not found" on any block explorer, as you say, it never went through, so they probably still have your coins.

Comment: thanks  Chak can you please help with my problem-people are saying they had transaction not found but got their bitcoin in 3-4 daysI will pay you $200 from the $1600 or so if you can help  recover, thanks quraish